# How to load Blobproperty image in Google App Engine?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, upload

I wrote some codes.

I could save image in BobProperty.

But I cannot load image into HTML page...

source code:

class Product(db.Model):

```
        image = db.BlobProperty()
            ...
```

class add:

```
  productImage = self.request.get('image')

  product.image = db.Blob(productImage)

  product.put()
```

but i wrote {{product.image}} into html code. But there were like ��袀 ���� ���� ���� (����������� ��(:(������� (������� (��>̢��� (�������>������Y������K��׏

What should i do if i want load image from datastore?

Answer (score 5):

I use an auxiliary view:

```
def serve_image(request, image):
    if image == "None":
        image = ""

    response = HttpResponse(image)
    response['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
    response['Cache-Control'] = "max-age=7200"
    return response
```

and in the model:

```
def get_image_path(self):
    # This returns the url of serve_image, with the argument of image's pk.
    # Something like /main/serve_image/1231234dfg22; this url will return a
    # response image with the blob
    return reverse("main.views.serve_image", args=[str(self.pk)])
```

and just use `{{ model.get_image_path }}` instead.

(this is django-nonrel, but I guess you could figure out what it does)

Also, there is a post  [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/serving_dynamic_images.html)  about this; you should check it out.