# How to render image to templates?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load Blobproperty image in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283001/how-to-load-blobproperty-image-in-google-app-engine)

I am reading an image as a byte string. I am saving  it into database. 
in models image field is :

```
image = db.BlobProperty(required=False)
```

I am rendering it to template using:
`context['image_obj'] = image_obj` (object of the Image models)

in template i am trying to render it like , I am using django:

```
{{ image_obj.image }}
```

But it shows nothing in template..

Comment: This was covered befor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283001/how-to-load-blobproperty-image-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet here as Django doesn't support blob type:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1597/